# Python equivalent of following AES encryption java code?

Tags: java, python-3.x, encryption, aes

A public API requires me to encrypt the payload using AES.

They have provided the following java code.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
import static java.util.Base64.getUrlDecoder;
import static java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder;
import static javax.crypto.Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE;
import static javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE;

private static final String AES_ALGO = "AES";
private static final String KEY_ALGO = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
private static final String AES_CBC_PKCS5 = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private static final String secretKey = "ac12ghd75kf75r";
private static final String fi = "FIUID";


    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String salt) {
        final byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGO);
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), AES_ALGO);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_CBC_PKCS5);
            cipher.init(ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
            return getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes(UTF_8)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am trying to write the equivalent in python3.
This is what I have come up with.

```
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
from datetime import datetime

AES_ALGO = "AES"
KEY_ALGO = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256"
AES_CBC_PKCS5 = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
secretKey = "ac12ghd75kf75r"
fi = "FIUID"


BLOCK_SIZE = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)

def encrypt_payload(payload,salt=datetime.utcnow()):
    private_key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(
    hash_name = 'sha1', 
    password = b"ac12ghd75kf75r", 
    salt = b"031120201803460", 
    iterations = 65536, 
    dklen = 32 #256
    )
    raw = pad(payload)
    iv=bytearray(16)
    iv=iv.encode("utf8")
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)    
    return_val= base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw.encode("utf8")))
    return return_val
def test_encryption():
    payload = "txnid=T1234&sessionid=S1234&srcref=Srcref1234&userid=acme@perfios-aa&redirect=https://example.com"
    encrypted_payload = "6Zdz3bzzu3AKld4d_D_dDBIaTqbXKxPjKGzGQgxkrm-WeDhpFr9Ma_R_BAdekBmUNbAcYFsizzJydDhQAa-fu40KrI9PcauoEEqgxC1C1iot_-0Ues7H7UyoLYgDgbxDpzy8s7zB3AhAvCIlplcYqQ=="
    print(encrypt_payload(payload, "031120201803460")==encrypted_payload)
```

Though this does not produce the same encrypted text and the test fails.
How can I fix my encrypt function to be able to generate the same
encrypted payload for the given test.

EDIT:-

Incorporating Topaco comment.

```
def encrypt_payload(payload,salt=datetime.utcnow()):
    private_key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(
    hash_name = 'sha256', #sha1
    password = b"ac12ghd75kf75r", 
    salt = b"031120201803460", 
    iterations = 65536, 
    dklen = 32 #256
)
    raw = pad(payload)
    iv=bytearray(16)
    iv=bytes(iv)
    print(iv)
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return_val= base64.urlsafe_b64encode(cipher.encrypt(raw.encode("utf8")))
    return return_val
```

Comment: In the Java code SHA256 and Base64url encoding is used, in the Python code SHA1 and Base64 encoding. Also, the Python code concatenates IV and ciphertext, while the Java code does not. Adjust the Python code accordingly with `hash_name = 'sha256'` and `base64.urlsafe_b64encode(...)` and fix the inconsistency regarding concatenation. Note that a static IV and salt are insecure.

Comment: so i made the changes you pointed out, but the encrypted text is still different. This is what i got now PPQtAHoxFxDCE5hKlLS0RYWKnYS0IgufJuMWKm80D5dipcqCwNn_2gOHjK8igAKBA-aYtCil_jTtPfu9xqXsyPEiM5H1T8Rn5IR4_8cz3Zk_QoHA_1jw6I6NlpDIr_h8Ap9moabhAuKDbAz-CawVsw==

Comment: The python generated key is not signed while java generated is signed could that be a difference too??

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Anyway, `PPQt...` is produced by **both** codes, the posted Java code and the modified Python code, s. here for Java: https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/jwZ. I cannot reproduce `6Zdz...` with the Java code, this ciphertext was probably generated with other parameters.

Comment: ahh yes you are correct the payload is different for 6zdz.. this works thanks. Can you put it as an answer for me to accept and upovte?